# Swift 4 backgroundColor bug?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with transparency in my Views, especially with `UITableView`.

Just to make sure. I already have 3 years of experience with swift and this is the first time, I am getting this problem.

So in apple's docs it says the following: 
`backgroundColor`
The view's background color.

Changes to this property can be animated. The default value is nil, which results in a transparent background color."

But when applying clear color to `backgroundColor` or `tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`, the background is still appearing white.

Is this a bug or a feature?

EDIT:

The tableView isn't the problem anymore. It is the cell within the tableView.
Already tried solutions are clearing the background color of all subviews. Nothing changed.

EDIT 29.09.17

Ok, I debugged my application and got this:

UICachedDeviceWhiteColor and cachedColor.

[image: UICachedDeviceWhiteColor]

A google searching also didn't help.

Edit 29.09.2017 Later that day ...

The problem occurs, when updating from swift 3 to swift 4.
I made a new project with swift 4, but it actually works fine.
Because it is a problem I have to solve. I will try some things and update this post from time to time.

Comment: There is `contentView` on top of `backgroundView`, play around with that view.

Comment: Can you show us the full code?

Comment: You should check your view hierarchy, it might be that behind your UITableView there is some other UIView that has a .white backgroundColor.

Comment: Is the background behind the table view white??

Comment: Thank you guys for your fast response.
There is indeed another view behind my tableView. I cleared the background, too, but nothing changed.
Before upgrading to swift 4 it worked.

Comment: @ Bruno Rocha
Showing the Code won't help you because you can reproduce this situation in 1 minute on your own ;)

Comment: the _table view's background_ colour, the _tableview cell's background_ colour, the cell's _content view's background_ colour, and optionally the _tableview's superview's background_ colour are 4 different things actually.

Comment: @holex 
I am aware of this order and carefully implementing my tableView with this in my mind.

Just to make sure that the tableView is the problem, I decided to set the alpha to 0.0 and it disappeared.
But when setting a color with an alpha the backGround stays white

Comment: @user2982195, probably, because either _the tableview cell's background_ colour, _content view's background_ colour, or _tableview's superview's background_ colour is still white, I suppose.

Comment: Ok...
So I made a loop:
for subview in cell.subviews{
    subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
But it's still there and doesn't show the background color of my super view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: 
When instantiating a variable which holds the view before displaying it, the background color of this view is white. The debugger calls this UICachedDeviceWhiteColor.

Why would you do that? 
If you instantiate the view before it is displayed, you can switch with a menu between different views very fast with "bringSubview(toFront: ...).

How to fix:
To fix this you have to instantiate the view every time you want to show it.

Hope I could help some lost souls with this answer and Apple is going to fix this bug.

Comment: Oh man... I've been pulling my hair out since yesterday. I literally duplicated another view with the EXACT SAME F*FHUING CODE and I'm having a white background on one of the two, consistently. What the hell...
Will try to solution now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In UITableViewCell and UICollectionViewCell there is a property view called contentView.

A common mistake is to manipulate the cell directly. Instead try to manipulate the cells **content view**:

```
Obj-c

UITableViewCell *cell = ....// get the cell

cell.backgroundColor = ... // BAD !

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor] // this is the correct way.
```

Swift

```
let cell = ...
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red // make sure its the contentView
```

also a couple small nuances with colors and opacity:

If you want **only** the background to have opacity (i.e. less than 100%) , make sure you are **not** changing the view's opacity (i.e. `view.alpha = 0.5` BAD) - change the **color's opacity** value instead:

i.e.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:... green:... blue:... alpha:0.5];
```

Another useful trick is to pause the application and press the "visual debug" button.

Search for your view and check it's attributes in the inspector

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the view behind it is not white, then set the current view's (the one with the transparent background) `modalPresentationStyle` to `overCurrentContext`. This will allow views behind to show through the UIColor.clear background color.

Comment: Please Google "Swift modal presentation style" to find a detailed tutorial. In order to see through a view with a clear background color you will need to do this successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting

```
tableView.backgroundColor = .red
```

and if it's an empty TableView then the Red will be visible. I give a headerView and FooterView also to visualise.

[image: simulator screen shot - iphone se - 2017-12-09 at 16 02 40]

**Now TableView Contents some data, so to reflect the color you need to set background color to cell.**

```
class UserCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
     backgroundColor = .yellow
}
.... 
}
```

[image: simulator screen shot - iphone se - 2017-12-09 at 16 04 18]
[image: simulator screen shot - iphone se - 2017-12-09 at 16 04 30]

[You can check out the original project here.](https://github.com/ashislaha/Learn-iOS/tree/master/06.%20Table%20View%20Explore/ExploreTableView/ExploreTableView)